# How to pass the and select the string from a text file?

Tags: string, text, command-line

I want to search the strings starting with "double" in a text file and pass the line numbers to two variable (Suppose I know there must be two lines have "double"). Next, I want to get the numbers in those strings and pass them to other two variables. After that, I want to delete those lines in the text. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows?  Or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the line numbers in 2 variables, `var1` and `var2` try this:

```
read var1 var2 <<< $(grep -Fnm 2 double file | cut -d: -f1)
```

Now `var1` and `var2` contain the line numbers of the lines containing the word `double`.

To "pass them" to two other variables:

```
foo="$var1"
bar="$var2"
```

To delete the lines, use `sed` as shown below:

```
sed "${var1}d;${var2}d;" file
```